# Change background color onclick and then retrieve the original color android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

In my application I have extended the base adapter and created my own adapter. I have different background images for the rows depends on their position. I want to change the color of any row when clicked " ACCOMPLISHED" AND THEN retrieve the first background color after the executing the onclick. Here's my onclick method that changes the background color.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if(pos==0)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stoprow);
            else if(pos==getCount()-1)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sbottomrow);
            else
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smiddlerow);

            Intent details = new Intent(v.getContext(),HomeworkDetails.class);
            details.putExtra("date", data.get(pos).getDateOfAdd() );
            details.putExtra("dueDate", data.get(pos).getDuedate());
            details.putExtra("course", data.get(pos).getCourse());
            details.putExtra("note", data.get(pos).getNote());
            details.putExtra("iconLink", links.get(pos));
            v.getContext().startActivity(details);
        }
        });
```

Now how can I change the background color after the `onclick()` ?

Comment: I don't understand, **when** you want to give the view its old background? you can get the old background with getBackground() before applying a new one, and you can invalidate() the list to make your custom adapter redraw it. I probably didn't understand the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use drawable with selector within. Declare two items with pressed atribute. One true and other false.

You can then asign drawable to button in your adapter.

Example drawable with selector within:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_on" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" /></selector>
```